# Closing children windows from Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, object-persistence

I have been searching high and low for a solution to my problem and can only find pieces of the puzzle with no way to connect them.  I have a window (which it self is a child of the main window) that can open multiple other windows.  I want the children windows to be closed when the parent is closed, sounds simple enough right?

Here is the dilemma, my parent window does a postback when opening the child so any array of handles (which are also objects) I keep does not persist.  I have looked into serializing and de-serializing this array and storing it in a hidden field but that doesn't seem like the best solution.  I also can not access the parent of the window doing the opening.

Aside from Javascript, the server side code is written in C# and I'm using asp.net.  Is there any reasonable solution to this?  I should also mention that the code I am working with was written by multiple different people long before I got to it so I would like to add to it rather than changing how most of it works.

Finally, I know it is typically a good idea to post my code on here but I am simply using `var win = window.open` to perform the window opening task.

Thank you.

Comment: I'd suggest using modal style popups for this (like jquery dialogues).
Most browsers close windows anyway and you can't climb back up the  window tree which means if you have 5 open and you close window 2 from window 1, then window's 3, 4, and 5 will remain open.

Comment: I can look into doing this, my biggest problem is that I am not supposed to be changing the way things currently work, just adding functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I then see 3 ways to get around that problem:

- Don't use multiple browser windows, but style your page to show all the dialogues; as @Gats suggested. OK, that will somewhat limit you if you want the input of parent "windows" persistant while navigating in a child window.
- Don't do a refresh postback to unload the parent. Use Ajax instead to send data to the application server
- You can't store (window) objects, you only can store strings. When opening a window, you can give it a "target" name, and any other `window.open` with the same target (name) will use the already open one. With that, you can reference windows you didn't open yourself - and close them. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/563478/1048572

Comment: The third option seems like something I might be able to use but doesn't the name have to be something like "_blank" or "_self"?  I know I can open multiple windows with the same url and a name of "_blank".

Comment: naa, different urls and names like "modal-dialogoue-child-1" (and so on), so that you can tell them apart

Comment: I used the third option along with some server side code and finally got this working.  I appreciate all of the help.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
var wins = [];
function newChildWindow(...) {
    wins.push(window.open(...));
}
window.onuload = function() {
    for (var i=0; i<wins.length; i++)
        if (!wins[i].closed)
            wins[i].close();
};
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the array of window objects does not persist to the point where I need them.

Comment: Why would it not persist? The array will persist until the window is closed, won't it?

Comment: The parent window does a postback which refreshes it, resetting any javascript variables.  I have tried to store the object in the viewstate or in a hidden field but it needs to be serialized.

Comment: ah, allright. Didn't read that carefully enough. See my other answer then